# Need a sorted hashmap by value where value is state is constantly changing

Tags: java, hashmap

I need a hashmap solution whereby the key is an Investor Object that is unique, and value is a Portfolio object.

The problem is that I need Investors to be sorted by their Portfolio Object, which has a total Value inside, which is changing constantly as he/she buys/sells stocks.

How can one solve this issue? 
thanks!

Comment: see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: Actually, I don't think the above will work well since I believe the TreeMap only sorts on insertion.

Comment: So, how do you need to get the Portfolios? Do you just need to get a sorted list of Portfolios or do you need to iterate the Map (key and value) in order by Portfolio value?

Comment: At the moment, i only need to know who is my top investor with the largest portfolio value. Hence i need the map sorted....

Comment: Given that, I think doing something similar to a combination of Anish post and my answer is probably best. Create a method that will sort the values (or entries) in the Map and return the sorted list (SortedSet) or the first / last entry. Just ensure that the data doesn't change during the sort process. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, I think the best solution is to store the values in a standard `Map` but provide a method to get the Portfolios in order `ImmutableSortedSet<Portfolio> getSortedPortfolios()`. The method would get the list of values and put them in the `Set`. This assumes that `Portfolios implements Comparable` otherwise you would need to provide a `Comparator`.

```
ImmutableSortedSet<Portfolio> getSortedPortfolios(){
   return ImmutableSortedSet.builder()
             .addAll(myMap.getValues())
             .build();
}
```

If you really need thread-safety I would recommend using a copy-constructor to create snapshots and insert them. This would ensure that the returned sorted list remains sorted.

```
ImmutableSortedSet<Portfolio> getSortedPortfolios(){
   ImmutableSortedSet.Builder<Portfolio> builder = ImmutableSortedSet.builder();

   for (Portfolio p : myMap.getValues()){
      builder.add(new Portfolio(p));
   }

   return builder.build();
}
```

I am using Guava's [ImmutableSortedSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet.html) here, but you could just use a `SortedSet` and treat it as immutable or use Collection.unmodifiable...

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I need Investors to be sorted by their Portfolio Object, which has a total Value inside, which is constantly as he/she buys/sells stocks.

The "constantly changing" is the tricky part here.

AFAIK, is no efficient (i.e. O(logN) or better performance) data structure that can keep something sorted on a constantly changing value.  All general purpose map API's I've come across assume that keys don't change while a mapping is a member of the map.

So, what I think you will have to use an event mechanism to track "change of value" events for the  `Portfolio` object.  The event handler would need to atomically remove the Portfolio from the ordered mapping, make the change, and then add it back in again at the new position.

To implement the data structures you need either a pair of maps or a bidirectional map.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `Java` collection library does not have a data structure to suit your requirement. But you can use `TreeBidiMap` in the [common collection library](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/TreeBidiMap.html)

Comment: Wouldn't the TreeBidiMap have to resort the tree whenever a value changed? Is it able to do this?